# How can an odd set of integers include even numbers as well?

Tags: integers

[Given Question](http://www.proprofs.com/sat/study-guide/Topic1/N_O_M2_S1/html/12015.shtml?score=11111111111111)

Now, when I see the explanation, it says:

> (-11) + (-9) + (-7) + .... + 0 + .... + 7 + 9 + 11 = 0, so the first
>   23 numbers cancel each other and the sum is 0. Then 13 + 15 = 28.
>   Therefore there are a total of 25 integers.

However, in the question, it is given that it is a set of *odd integers.* How is it the case that the answer includes the number of even numbers as well?

Comment: What is your question? Are you wondering why the designers of this multiple choice test decided to include $24$ among the wrong suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't. They probably wrote the +0 in the middle instead of (-1+1) and (-3+3) etc, choosing to point out that they total zero (as opposed to zero being present as one of the numbers)

Comment: @JMoravitz Even if you add up all the positive and negative odd numbers till 11, even then you get only 13 numbers and plus two = 15.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. The cardinality of $\{-11,-9,-7,\ldots, 7,9,11,13,15\}$ is in fact much less than $25$ (oh, counting ...)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen :D :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the suggested answers, the question does not have a unique answer. For example, $\{-11, 39\}$ is a set of odd integers that has $-11$ as least member and the sum is $28$ and so is $\{-11,-5,7,37\}$.

In general, if the set had an odd number of elements, the sum would be odd because all summands are odd. That immediately rules out the answer options $11,23,25$.

The minimal sum that $22$ distinct (because the problem statement talks about a set!) odd integers $\ge -11$ could produce is
$$-11-9-7-5-3-1+1+3+5+7+9+11+\\+13+15+17+19+21+23+25+27+29+31 \gg28 $$
and with $24$ summands it gets even worse.

Conclusion: Dump that test.

Comment: I would give $-11-9-7-\cdots-1+1+\cdots+29+31$ for the conclusion, if that option was available.

Comment: However you meant "The minimal sum that _a set of_ $22$ odd integers$\geq11$ could produce"; normally a sum of odd integers could contain the same term more than once. But the test indeed says "a set".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Duely noted